# DWAPlannerROS vs TrajectoryPlannerROS

Tags: ros, navigation, 3d-navigation, dwa-local-planner, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am currently looking to implement my own local planner plugin for the navigation stack. I was looking at DWAPlannerROS and TrajectoryPlannerROS to help me start with. Though I am not sure I understand the relation between these 2 planners. Are they just 2 different local planners or is one part of the second?

I am asking because, as far as I understand from [this wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner) and [the source](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/base_local_planner/include/base_local_planner/trajectory_planner_ros.h), the DWA algorithm is implemented twice. Once in TrajectoryPlannerROS and another time in DWAPlannerROS.

Am I correct in saying so? And if so, is there a reason why the DWA is coded twice?

Now, if I understand [this section](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner#Generic_Local_Planning), I believe the recommended way to implement a new local planner plugin is to inherit DWAPlanner. Do you confirm?

I am asking because there is a [clean tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS) so as to write custom global planners, but I could not find an equivalent for local planners.

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196862/dwaplannerros-vs-trajectoryplannerros/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-11-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2014-11-06**:
This might also be helpful: http://answers.ros.org/question/10718/dwa_planner-vs-base_local_planner/?answer=15804#post-id-15804

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-11-06**:
Haha good point! Thanks ;)

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2015-01-22**:
If we want to change/update trajectories (instruct the automated navigator to follow our trajectory)then which local_planner should be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In principle you can just implement the bare base_local_planner interface. The idea of the section you cited is that some functionality is quite common among local planners, e.g. checkTrajectory. If your local planner behaves similarly it would be a good idea to use the same code. What makes more sense for you depends on your algorithm.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-11-06**:
Okey dok, understood. Thanks for your help!